# How do I install FFMPEG in Heroku and use it?

Tags: heroku, ffmpeg, discord.py

I would like to use FFMPEG for my bot that I want to host on Heroku. For this I installed the following buildpack: `https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest`.
I added some checks in my source code to check the FFMPEG path:

```py
source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(
            discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(song.stream_url, executable=FFMPEG_PATH, before_options=beforeArgs),
            volume=state.volume)
```

and the path is:

```py
FFMPEG_PATH = parser.get('MUSIC', 'ffmpeg-path')
```

In a config file I then have the following:

```py
ffmpeg-path : /usr/bin/ffmpeg
```

But this does not seem to be the correct path. So how do I get the path of the buildpack at Heroku?

Comment: Shouldn't need the path. Just have it call `ffmpeg`; it should be in `$PATH` already.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks, that helped, also added `heroku-opus` to avoid errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the FFMPEG working on Heroku you have to install the following packs:

`https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest` - FFMPEG.
`https://github.com/xrisk/heroku-opus` - Avoids `OpusNotLoaded()` errors.

You can add them under `Settings/Buildpacks`.
The default path, if needed, is `ffmpeg`.
You can then launch the bot.